Lower bounds of sieves for factorization
Among factoring algorithms, both the Quadratic Sieve and the Number Field Sieve use sieves to find smooth (pairs of) values, in order to obtain congruent squares $\bmod n$, the number to be factored. I want to improve on these methods. But I wonder if I can do better, meaning coming up with a quasipolynomial-time algorithm, still with sieves. In other words, is there a (subexponential) lower bound for sieves? Do I have to abandon sieves and seek other ways?

Are you able to provide any formalization/definition of what you would consider to constitute a "sieve"?  Or is it part of the question how even to define that?

@D.W.: Since the target audience is not familiar with sieves, let me explain how it works. First you have a factor base, say ${2,3,\ldots,p_r}$ for the first $r$ primes. You want to collect "smooth" values, i.e., values whose prime factors are all from the factor base. Let's say we sieve on the range $[1,1000]$. Initialize an array $a$, where $a[i]=i$. Then we go over multiples of $2$ in the array and divide the array values by $2$. After that we go over multiples of $3$ and divide the array values by $3$, and so on. In the end, array positions with values equal to $1$ are smooth.

Does the following theorem imply such a lower bound? It appears on page 286 of Prime Numbers: A Computational Perspective, 2nd edition.

Theorem 6.2.2 (Pomerance 1996a). Suppose $m_1,m_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of integers in $[1,X]$, each chosen independently and with uniform distribution. Let $N$ be the least integer such that a nonempty subsequence from $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_N$ has product being a square. Then the expected value for $N$ is $L(X)^{\sqrt2+o(1)}$. The same expectation holds if we also insist that each $m_j$ used in the product be $B$-smooth, with $B=L(X)^{1/\sqrt2}$.

The definition of $L(n)$ appears on page 265.

$$L(n)=e^{\sqrt{\ln n\ln\ln n}}.\tag{6.1}$$

And for interested readers, the reference is

[Pomerance 1996a] C. Pomerance. Multiplicative independence for random integers. In Analytic Number Theory, Vol. 2 (Allerton Park, IL, 1995), volume 139 of Progr. Math., pages 703–711. Birkhäuser, 1996.

On page 705 of the above reference, it is said that

The lower bound has been implicitly conjectured in many heuristic factorization analyses but a proof has never been given. This turns out to be a fairly hard problem and is the heart of this paper.
Our main theorem is not directly applicable to the analysis of existing factorization algorithms, but the method of its proof is.

